# How to implement Image gallery with single image representing file in image directory

Tags: android, subdirectory, image-gallery

I am trying to implement a feature like Instagram or WhatsApp, where the thumbnail of a single image that exists in a folder in android, is shown on top of a list item, more like a sample of what kinds of image are in the folder.

Help me to understand this feature.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but I think you want to know how to show a layout on another layout, but the layout below would still be visible, am I right ? If that is what you want to achieve, just don't put a background colour on the layout above. If you have set `android:windowBackground` in `style.xml` or `theme.xml`, then you might want to either remove that or set `android:background="#000000"` on the layout above. `#000000` means a transparent color.

Comment: I don't mean like. I meaning Instagram saving feature. You can see the saved posts preview in top of directory.

Comment: Do you want to implement an image gallery or something? Where a single photo that exists in the directory stays on top of the image directory

Comment: Yeah yes. I don't know how to call that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I implemented it. It might not be the best though, but it works.

1. I fetched the URIs of all the images using [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore), you can learn how to use it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media).
2. The First step was done in a background thread to prevent it from blocking the UI thread.
3. I sorted out the images I got, grouping them in a `List<Image>`, which would represent a single directory.
4. I then added the `List<Image>` into a `List<List<Image>>`, which served as the overall images that were fetched and have their total size which I used later to track the number of images in the directory.

The code is below.

```
   @Override
   public void run() {
      Uri storageUri;
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
         storageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
      } else {
         storageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
      }

    // the queries to the MediaStore API (The image details or metadata I need

      String[] projection = {
              MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
              MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
              MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
              MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};

     // now query the MediaStore API using ContentResolver    
      Cursor imgCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(storageUri, projection, null, null, null);

      int bucketId = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
      int imgSize = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE);
      int name = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
      int bucketName = imgCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

     // directoryDictionary is a temporary list of directory names that was found, while querying the MediaStore API

      List<String> directoryDictionary = new ArrayList<>();

     // generalList is just a list that would represent a general image list, where all images can be found. Just like Whatsapp

      List<Image> generalList = new ArrayList<>();

      while (imgCursor.moveToNext()) {
         long id = imgCursor.getLong(bucketId);
         int size = imgCursor.getInt(imgSize);
         String fileName = imgCursor.getString(name);
         String folderName = imgCursor.getString(bucketName);

        // As recommended by the Android developers doc

         Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

        // a single image

         Image currentImage = new Image(contentUri, size, fileName, folderName);


         // add all images to the general image list, but modifying the directory name

         Image genImage = new Image(contentUri, size, fileName, "All Media");
         generalList.add(genImage);

         int directoryIndex = CollectionUtils.linearSearch(directoryDictionary, folderName);
         // if search result (directoryIndex) passes this test, then it means that there is
         // no such directory in list of directory names
         if (directoryIndex < 0) {
            imageDirectoryList.add(new ArrayList<>());
            directoryDictionary.add(folderName);
            directoryIndex = CollectionUtils.linearSearch(directoryDictionary, folderName);
            if (directoryIndex >= 0)
               imageDirectoryList.get(directoryIndex).add(currentImage);
         } else {
            imageDirectoryList.get(directoryIndex).add(currentImage);
         }
      }

      //...then add it if the image list of folder is > 2
      if (imageDirectoryList.size() > 2) imageDirectoryList.add(0, generalList);

      imgCursor.close();
      runOnUiThread(() -> {
         // imageAdapter is the RecyclerView's list Adapter.
         // notifyDataSetChanged() must be call to refresh list.

         imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // doViewUpdate was just used to turn on and off the visibility of some views

         doViewUpdate();
      });
   }
```